# project name directory is not getting created in rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I am beginner for rundeck. i installed `rundeck 3.2` on `centos7` using rpm package. After installation I changed the hostname in framework properties and rundeck-config file. And put the *iptable rule from 80 to 4440*.

I created the project on rundeck gui but i can't found project-name directory in `/var/lib/rundeck/projects`. Can you please help me on the same?

Second i installed the 3.0 version as well where i project directory is there in `/var/rundeck/projects`. but `resources.xml` is not getting read. I was using vis password not from key exchange.

Support will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In rundeck 3.2 the default folder changed to "/var/lib/rundeck/projects"

You will find more info in the following link https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.2.html#upgrading-from-rundeck-3-0-using-debian-rpm-packaging

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply, i know that path has been changed which i mentioned in my port.

I was saying after creating the project from gui, i didn't find the project folder under the /var/lib/rundeck/projects location, even i tried with manual creation of project-name/etc folder and placed the resources.xml. But no luck.

//Bharat

Answer (score 0):

if you defined projects to be saved in the database in

Example (rundeck-config.properties)

**rundeck.projectsStorageType=db** << project config saved and read in database.

OR

**rundeck.projectsStorageType=file** << project config will be saved and read in Filesystem.

You can check this line by doing a grep

```
# cat /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties | grep rundeck.projectsStorageType
```

All your project config will be saved/read according to this setting. If you create/modify files in the filesystem and you are using the database to read/save project settings, your changes will not take effect.